# How much of Metropolis is Toronto?

Tags: dc, superman

[Joe Shuster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Shuster) was the co-creator and original artist of Superman.  Shuster was born and raised in Toronto, where he was a paper boy for *The Toronto Star*.  (For those of you who know Toronto well, he lived in and around Kensington Market.)

> In the original version Superman's mild-mannered alter ego, Clark Kent, worked for *The Daily Star*, which was patterned after *The Toronto Star*. The newspaper's name in the strip was changed later to The *Daily Planet*.

([Source](http://thecanadianencyclopedia.com/en/article/joe-shuster/))

To clarify the preceding passage, I should add that *The Toronto Star*  was *[The Toronto Daily Star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toronto_Star#In_popular_culture)*  when Shuster was growing up.

> Superman co-creator Joe Shuster modeled the look of Metropolis after his home town of Toronto, Ontario, Canada (though Metropolis was never depicted as a Canadian city).

([Source](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Metropolis))

**Other than the Daily Planet, are there any other specific Toronto landmarks that are seen or referenced, either in name or appearance, within Metropolis in the comics?**

Comment: This question is somewhat complicated by the fact that Metropolis is supposed to be a Midwestern city, but bears the most resemblance to New York City.

Comment: @WadCheber : I'm just interested in any specific Toronto references --- street names, buildings, parks, other landmarks, etc.  Anything that is distinctly "Toronto" that has appeared in Metropolis (even if Metropolis has, in the large, become New York).  :-)

Comment: I don't think you're going to be happy with the results.  The Wikipedia entry on Metropolis mentions Toronto exactly once.  The "Superman Super Site" entry on "Fictional City of Metropolis" mentions it three times.  Both say that the story was originally set in Cleveland, but quickly relocated to Metropolis, which later became an analogy for NYC.  For what it is worth, the one reference to Metropolis on the wiki page says only that Shuster wanted the skyline to be modeled on Toronto.  I doubt that any trace of Toronto survived into the comic books.

Comment: The fact that the Statue of Liberty is in "Metropolis Harbor" says everything that needs to be said about it.

Comment: I could write a hell of an answer about Metropolis' similarities to NYC, but I haven't found enough information about the connection between Metropolis and Toronto to write a full paragraph.  Every bit of that information is already included in your question.  The answer appears to be "Little to none".

Comment: @WadCheber : All of that could be an answer --- sometimes the answers we *don't want* to hear are the best ones.  :-)

Comment: @WadCheber : Even if the Toronto-esque aspects of Metropolis were quickly left behind, I'd be interested to know how Shuster's original drawing of Metropolis' skyline (which I haven't seen) compares to the Toronto of the time.

Comment: I'll wait a while to see if anyone else can give you the answer you are hoping for. If no such answer appears, I'll destroy your hopes and dreams.  :)

Comment: @WadCheber : Give it a day, and then come back to it if you like.  I'll brace myself for impact.  ;-)

Comment: @WadCheber I'm pretty sure that Metropolis being in the Midwest is more or less unique to Smallville. It is usually depicted as being vaguely on the Northern East Coast, sometimes adjacent to New York and/or Gotham.

Comment: @Politank-Z - Impossible.  I know about the Midwest idea, and I never saw Smallville.  I must have heard it somewhere else.

Comment: @WadCheber On looking further, it seems that Metropolis was sometimes put near Chicago in Lois & Clark, and was once identified as being in Kansas in Superman: The Animated Series (though that was contradicted later). Still, it is usually somewhere on the Northeast Corridor.

Comment: @Politank-Z - My guess is that I heard it in the Batman comics, because I used to read them when I was a kid.

Comment: http://goodcomics.comicbookresources.com/2010/08/26/comic-book-legends-revealed-275/

Comment: Great find, @Richard!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### TL;DR:  Not much.

---

Metropolis was modeled on Toronto and Cleveland, but bears little resemblance to either. In fact, Shuster's Metropolis looks like no city on earth - it is just a vague art-deco shape in the background.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Shuster did talk about Toronto:

> “Cleveland was not nearly as metropolitan as Toronto was, and it was not as big or as beautiful. Whatever buildings I saw in Toronto remained in my mind and came out in the form of Metropolis. As I realized later on, Toronto is a much more beautiful city than Cleveland ever was.” Pausing for a moment, Shuster chuckles and adds, “I guess I don’t have to worry about saying that now.”

But compare his drawings to the actual cities of Cleveland and Toronto at that time:

[image]
<sup>*Cleveland in the 1930's*</sup>

[image]
<sup>*Toronto in the 1930's*</sup>

And you'd be hard pressed to see any similarities to Shuster's Metropolis.

The one clear connection to Toronto was quickly retconned out of the story, when the "Daily Star" (named after the *Toronto Daily Star*) became the "Daily Planet".

[image]
<sup>*The Toronto Daily Star*</sup>

[image]
<sup>*The Daily Star*</sup>

[image]
<sup>*First appearance of The Daily Planet, in a [February 26, 1942 Fleischer Superman short](http://www.smithsonianmag.com/arts-culture/the-architecture-of-superman-a-brief-history-of-the-daily-planet-22037/?no-ist)*</sup>

[image]
<sup>*First comic book appearance of [The Daily Planet, Superman #19, 1942](http://goodcomics.comicbookresources.com/2010/09/17/comic-book-legends-revealed-278/)*</sup>

Comment: Nice work, Wad!  Thanks for giving this your attention.  I see no reason not to accept this.  Just a note: some of the early comic panels (such as the 4th one in your answer) show a skyline resembling very much what Toronto would have looked like at the time when Shuster was young, when the Royal York Hotel (once the tallest building in the British Empire) [dominated](http://torontopath.com/wp-content/uploads/fairmont-royal-york-hotel-1.jpg) the Toronto skyline.  Add that in if you wish, but either way, consider your answer accepted.  :-)

Comment: Built in 1929, 5 years after Shuster left Toronto.

Comment: I think the tall, skinny, pointy building in picture #4 might be modeled on [Terminal Tower in Cleveland](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b1/Tower_City.jpg).

Comment: The Daily Planet building appears to be modeled on the [Paramount Building in NYC](http://public.media.smithsonianmag.com/legacy_blog/paramount-building-nyc.jpg)

Comment: He didn't leave Toronto permanently after 1924.  He had family there and visited frequently.  The Royal York was constructed 10 years before *Action Comics* #1.

Comment: But I take your point about the other two buildings.  :-)